# Mutating HashMap at multiple places

Tags: rust

I am trying to write a B2B market simulation model in Rust, i.e. several firms ought to sell products to each other.

I have this firm structure:

```rust
struct Firm {
    product: String,
    capital: f64,
    price: f64,
    sales: f64,
}
```

Products are modeled as strings from a certain set of strings: (could be a string array or even an `enum`, but will be dynamically loaded form a file during runtime)

```rust
let products = vec![String::from("A"), String::from("B"), String::from("C"),
                    String::from("A1"), String::from("A2"), String::from("A3"),
                    String::from("B1"), String::from("B2"), String::from("C1")];
```

For convenience, I wrap all firms and products into a `Model` structure:

```rust
struct Model {
    products: Vec<String>,
    firms: HashMap<usize, Firm>,
}
```

For each product, I find out what inputs are required (in this simple example, two-char products are inputs for the single-char products, e.g. "A1", "A2", "A3" are inputs to "A"). Then, I do a loop over the firms producing that product (e.g. "A") and for each firm a nested loop over the inputs to find the cheapest firm selling that input (e.g. "A1").

The problem I am facing is that I find myself needing two mutable references to the `HashMap` `model.firms`, simultaneously. I need a mutable reference to the buying firm to decrease its capital and a mutable reference to the selling firm to increase its capital. This seems impossible in Rust since I "cannot borrow `model.firms` as mutable more than once at a time".

This is the entire code:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

const START_CAPITAL: f64 = 100_000.00;

struct Model {
  products: Vec<String>,
  firms: HashMap<usize, Firm>,
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
struct Firm {
  product: String,
  capital: f64,
  price: f64,
}

fn setup() -> Model {
  // define some example products just for illustration:
  let products = vec![String::from("A"), String::from("B"), String::from("C"),
                      String::from("A1"), String::from("A2"), String::from("A3"),
                      String::from("B1"), String::from("B2"), String::from("C1")];
  
  let mut firms = HashMap::new();
  // insert some example firms just for illustration:
  firms.insert(0, Firm{product: String::from("A"), capital: START_CAPITAL, price: 10_000.00});
  firms.insert(1, Firm{product: String::from("B"), capital: START_CAPITAL, price: 10_000.00});
  firms.insert(2, Firm{product: String::from("C"), capital: START_CAPITAL, price: 10_000.00});
  firms.insert(3, Firm{product: String::from("A1"), capital: START_CAPITAL, price: 1200.00});
  firms.insert(4, Firm{product: String::from("A1"), capital: START_CAPITAL, price: 1400.00});
  firms.insert(5, Firm{product: String::from("A2"), capital: START_CAPITAL, price: 2300.00});
  firms.insert(6, Firm{product: String::from("A2"), capital: START_CAPITAL, price: 2500.00});
  firms.insert(7, Firm{product: String::from("A3"), capital: START_CAPITAL, price: 1800.00});
  firms.insert(8, Firm{product: String::from("B1"), capital: START_CAPITAL, price: 2600.00});
  firms.insert(9, Firm{product: String::from("B2"), capital: START_CAPITAL, price: 3100.00});
  firms.insert(10, Firm{product: String::from("C1"), capital: START_CAPITAL, price: 5000.00});
  
  Model {
    products: products,
    firms: firms,
  }
}

fn market(model: &mut Model) {
  for product in &model.products {
    if product.chars().count() == 1 {
      // this is an end product

      let input_products: Vec<&String> = model.products.iter()
        .filter(|name| name.starts_with(product) && name.chars().count() > 1).collect();

      // firms who sell this product need to buy inputs
      let input_buyers: Vec<&mut Firm> = model.firms.values_mut()
      //                                 ----------- first mutable borrow occurs here
        .filter(|firm| firm.product == *product).collect();

      for buyer in input_buyers {
      //           ------------ first borrow later used here
        for input in &input_products {
          // find out which firms sell this input product and buy from the cheapest
          let mut input_sellers: Vec<&mut Firm> = model.firms.values_mut()
          //                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
            .filter(|firm| firm.product == **input).collect();
          
          // find out which are the cheapeast sellers:
          input_sellers.sort_unstable_by(
            |firm1, firm2| firm1.price.partial_cmp(&firm2.price)
            .expect("Some error comparing prices")
          );

          // now we would let the firm buy from the cheapest seller:
          // decrease capital of buyer, increase capital of seller
          input_sellers[0].capital += input_sellers[0].price;
          buyer.capital -= input_sellers[0].price;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

fn main() {
  let mut model = setup();
  market(&mut model);
}
```

I already found a workaround that involves creating `Vec`s with clones of the buying and selling firms. That way, I do not borrow the `firms` `HashMap`. I can then, one at a time, get a mutable reference to the selling firm, change its capital, then get a mutable reference to the buying firm and do the same. The problem I am facing is the interweaving of mutable reference to buyer and seller in nested loops, which I am then avoiding. However, I find this workaround rather cumbersome and it requires more overhead for the cloning.

Is there an obvious better way to model this in Rust? I can think of storing the firms not in a single `HashMap` indexed by firm ID, but in separate vectors of `HashMap`s, one for each product. Then, I would not need to borrow the same data structure twice because seller and buyer would reside in distinct structures. But then, it becomes more complicated to directly access any firm by its ID.

Is there any better way? (I think [`split_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.split_mut) is not convenient here either, if even applicable.)

Comment: I would make `input_buyers` a `Vec<usize>` and store _keys_ instead of values: `let input_buyers: Vec<_> = model.firms.iter().filter(|(_, firm)| firm.product == *product).map(|(key, _) *key).collect();` That way you don't have an outstanding borrow. The price is that you have an extra hash lookup when you need to access the buyer, but if you can live with that, that's a simple and effective solution to the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the help of user4815162342's comment, I came up with this solution, storing and iterating over the firm IDs. I replaced the function `market` with this code:

```rust
// Returns immutable reference:
fn get_firm<'a>(id: &usize, firms: &'a HashMap<usize, Firm>) -> &'a Firm {
  firms.get(id).expect(&format!("Firm with ID `{}` not found in model", id))
}

// Returns mutable reference:
fn get_firm_mut<'a>(id: &usize, firms: &'a mut HashMap<usize, Firm>) -> &'a mut Firm {
  firms.get_mut(id).expect(&format!("Firm with ID `{}` not found in model", id))
}

// Returns vector with IDs of firms taking part in this market
fn market_firms(prod_name: &String, firms: &HashMap<usize, Firm>) -> Vec<usize> {
  firms.iter()
      .filter(|(_id, firm)| firm.product == *prod_name)
      .map(|(id, _firm)| *id).collect()
}

fn market(model: &mut Model) {
  for product in &model.products {
    if product.chars().count() == 1 {
      // this is an end product

      let input_products: Vec<&String> = model.products.iter()
        .filter(|name| name.starts_with(product) && name.chars().count() > 1).collect();

      // firms who sell this product need to buy inputs
      let input_buyer_ids = market_firms(product, &model.firms);

      for buyer_id in input_buyer_ids {
        for input in &input_products {
          // find out which firms sell this input product and buy from the cheapest
          let mut input_seller_ids = market_firms(input, &model.firms);
          
          // find out which are the cheapeast sellers:
          input_seller_ids.sort_unstable_by(
            |id1, id2| get_firm(id1, &model.firms).price.partial_cmp(&get_firm(id2, &model.firms).price)
            .expect("Some error comparing prices")
          );

          // decrease capital of buyer, increase capital of seller
          let amount = get_firm(&input_seller_ids[0], &model.firms).price;
          get_firm_mut(&input_seller_ids[0], &mut model.firms).capital += amount;
          get_firm_mut(&buyer_id, &mut model.firms).capital += amount;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The rest of the code remains unchanged. Any suggestions for improvement are welcome, but this at least seems to work.